# Changing hex value string to a system color string in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hex

I need to change the string value `"#FFF"` to the string `"white"`

Or `"#FF0000"` to `"red"`.

In the case that the hex value is not a system color, it would just use the hex value. `"#906"` would output `"#906"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you have to present the user with these options in UI, like for a color picker or something?

Comment: The user will enter a color value, either in hex format "#F00", or System Color "Red". If the hex value they entered in is a system color, I need to output the System color instead of the hex value.

Comment: Have you attempted any code yet? You should show us what you have.

Comment: System colors are variable and not alwayse the same, do you mean named colors such as red, green, etc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to map the system colors you could do something like this. Note that this also returns values for the system such as WindowBrush etc, which I filter out using the `continue` check. Note that I'm using c# 6 string interpolations here but you can concatenate however you like.

```
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;

...
{
    string input = $"#ff{myTextBox.Text}"; // let the user enter just the digits 

    input = input.ToLower(); // Needs to be lowercase, or you could use a case invariant check later

    string name;

    KnownColor[] values = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));

    for(int i =0; i <values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i <= 25 || i >= 167) continue; // Eliminate default wpf control colors

        int RealColor = Color.FromKnownColor(values[i]).ToArgb();

        string ColorHex = $"{RealColor:x6}";

        if ($"#{ ColorHex }"== input)
        {
            name = values[i].ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly though I would just create my own `Dictionary` of values and do a simple lookup, eg.:

```
var myColors = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"#FF000000", "Black"},
    ...
};

string colorName;

if (myColors.ContainsKey(myTextBox.Text))
    colorName = myColors[myTextBox.Text];
else
    colorName = myTextBox.Text;
```